# python Ошибка Invalid literal int with base 10

Tags: python

Я работаю в библиотеке Tkinter и у меня есть поле Entry, куда пользователь должен ввести число
Но то что находиться в поле Entry это String
Так вот я хочу перевести это число в int
И когда я пишу `N = int(ent.get())` у меня выбивает ошибку
Не понимаю в чем проблема, ведь можно же "2" изменить в String написав код int("2")

Comment: Добавьте больше кода

Comment: `N = int(ent.get().strip())` попробуй

Comment: @eri  все равно та же ошибка(((

Comment: Взял пример с Метанита https://metanit.com/python/tutorial/9.6.php
Заменил message.get() на int(message.get()).
При вводе числа "2" все работает.